# XPATH: Select text exactly matching pattern passed

Tags: xml, xpath

I have xpath like:

```
//span[text()[contains(.,"" + text + "")]]
```

If I have two Strings matching `text` value like: Apple, Red(Apple) my xpath select Red(Apple). How can I make it select exactly what I pass in, if I pass Apply I expect Apple.

For me this is not preferable to point exactly `div/span/etc` path to text. I want to search in all `spans` for directly `text` value path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, than use = instead of contains function.

```
//span[. = "" + text + ""]
```

f.x. for such XML

```
<fruits>
    <span id="1">Apple</span>
    <span id="2">Red(Apple)</span>
    <span id="3">Apple, Red(Apple)</span>
</fruits>
```

Such xPath would return you **Red(Apple)**

```
//span[.='Red(Apple)']
```

Result is

```
Element='<span id="2">Red(Apple)</span>'
```

Comment: It's a remarkably common mistake that people assume contains() means "node contains value". It actually means "string contains substring". Don't guess: read the spec.